# Head detection from top straight down view using OpenCV in Android

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

Can anyone please provide any pointers about Head detection using OpenCV.
My requirement is to detect the heads from a top straight down view(like one from ceiling). Please help..

Thanks,
Kariyachan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about training you own classifier for this?